# 404 Not Found when form is submitted but works when the same URL is reloaded

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I made a simple login system using ExpressJs and on submission of form the user is directed to www.mywebsite.com/submit and see "Not Found 404" but when i refresh the same page i see the view for that.

I am not sure why it is happening but here is the code

**Index.js(Route)**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

router.get('/submit', function(req, res){
res.render('submit');
});

module.exports = router;
```

**Submit.jade**

```
extends layout

block content
h1 Successfully Logged In
```

**404 Not Found Error**

```
Error: Not Found at Layer.app.use.res.render.message [as handle (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/nodejs/app.js:29:15) 
    at trim_prefix (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/nodejs/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:240:15)
    at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/nodejs/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:208:9
    at Function.proto.process_params (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/nodejs/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:269:12)
    at next (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/nodejs/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:199:19)
    at next (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/nodejs/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:176:38)
    at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/nodejs/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:137:5
    at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/nodejs/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:250:10
    at next (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/nodejs/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:160:14)
    at next_layer (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/nodejs/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:77:14)
```

Comment: You need to define a route for the post method by calling `router.post()`

Answer (score 0):

I guess the form is being submitted via POST, but you have defined the route only for GET

Comment: Yes it is submitted via POST but how to specifically define the route for POST?

Comment: router.post not working but when i tried to change form method="get" and tried with router.get, it worked.

I want method to be post.

Answer (score 0):

```
router.get('/submit', function(req, res){
    res.render('submit');
});
```

should be

```
router.post('/submit', function(req, res){
    res.render('submit');
});
```

According to the documentation:

> The app.VERB() methods provide the routing functionality in Express,
>   where VERB is one of the HTTP verbs, such as app.post().

Source: http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.VERB